# List<T> Find method in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, list, visual-c++, find, c++-cli

Why it doesn't work in C++/CLI ?

```
_list->Remove(_list->Find(x => x.Inode == 2));
```

I received an error `error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: This is not possible to troubleshoot without further context.  Posting more of your code would help.

Comment: Because that's C# syntax. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277612/Using-lambdas-Cplusplus-vs-Csharp-vs-Cplusplus-CX

Comment: C++/CLI doesn't support lambda expressions.  The language was frozen in 2005, no new bells and whistles were added to it since then.  You'll need to use a delegate explicitly.  C++11 got lambdas but they are not compatible with C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hans Passant's comment is the answer, so I'm just pasting it here:

> C++/CLI doesn't support lambda expressions. The language was frozen in 2005, no new bells and whistles were added to it since then. You'll need to use a delegate explicitly. C++11 got lambdas but they are not compatible with C++/CLI. –  Hans Passant

Answer (score 1):

As [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) commented, C++/CLI doesn't support lambda notation. If you need to use the Find method it can be done by creating your own delegate and invoking it with a new instance of

```
_list->Find(gcnew Predicate<T>(gcnew &MyDelegate(params)))
```

Here's a link to a snippet that I used: [Custom List::Find() Method in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37354500/how-do-i-create-a-custom-find-method-for-a-genericlistt-in-c-cli/37354501#37354501)