# How do I create a custom Find method for a Generic::List<T> in C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I wanted to post an answer to this question because the MSDN Network Example only lists C# and VB and the answer is a bit different in C++/CLI.

This answer is derived from this post: [Using "->Find" on a "List" in Visual C++](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d1faf3c-bcb9-4ef0-8f37-ff465a18e9a7/using-find-on-a-list-in-visual-c?forum=vclanguage)

Answer (score 2):

Following the guidance of the post link [above](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d1faf3c-bcb9-4ef0-8f37-ff465a18e9a7/using-find-on-a-list-in-visual-c?forum=vclanguage)...

First I created a class to use as my Predicate delegate:

```
public value class FindComponentView
{
  String^ Value;

public:

  FindComponentView(String^ value)
  {
    Value = value;
  }
  bool IsMatch(ComponentDrawingData^ compDD)
  {
    return compDD->Identifier->Value == Value;
  }
};
```

I was then able to implement the Find() method like this:

```
// Note: ComponentDrawingDataList^ derives from System::Collections::Generic::List<T>^

ComponentDrawingDataList^ ddList = GetComponentDrawingDatas(component);
ComponentDrawingData^ componentDrawingData = 
  ddList->Find(gcnew System::Predicate<ComponentDrawingData^>(gcnew FindComponentView("View_1"), &FindComponentView::IsMatch));
```